# Shell script to check all the URLs from a file or list

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, nagios

I'm looking for a shell script to check a list of URLs and give output. For example:

```
http://abc.com/index.php
http://abc1.com/index.php
```

I may place them in a separate file or inside the script. I need a valid HTTP response code for all these URLs. If all the URLs work, the response code must be `HTTP OK HTTP/1.1 200 OK`.

If any URL from the above URLs fails, I need output with an error message for that particular URL.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to install `wget` is you don't have it already:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS='
'
LIST='http://www.google.com
http://www.drk.com.ar/daphne.php
http://www.google.com/this-is-an-error
http://serverfault.com/questions
'
for I in $LIST
do
  wget -q --no-cache --spider $I
  if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    echo Error: $I
  fi
done
```